# Show selections from a checkbox as strings on an Android app screen

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I've looked around for this but haven't been able to find an answer - I'm relatively new to Java/Android so I apologize if it's a basic question.  I'm making an "edit profile" page in an Android application, and for one of the fields, I've created a checkbox dialog that opens on touching the field.  Once the user has checked the box(es) and closed the dialog, I want the selections to show on the "edit profile" screen in a list form.  For example, if the user checks "music" and "sports" in the list, I want those to show on the screen in the relevant field as "music, sports".  From looking around online, it seems that I might need to make an arraylist of the checked items and then convert them to strings...if so, how would I do this?  And once I have the strings, how would I show them on the page?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the setOnCheckedChangeListener to your checkbox;

```
            CheckBox box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           // either you can save the selection list in array list andupdate your main display layout after the dialog is closed . or Update the display layout on  every time check state changes.
                if(isChecked) {
                   // save the selection list in array list
                    arrayList.add(buttonView.getText());
                   // or else update the display layout.
                   textview.setText(buttonView.getText());
                } else {
                    arrayList.remove(buttonView.getText());
                   // update layout
                   textview.setText(buttonView.getText());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok great, thanks.  I know this is a whole new question, but could you give me a hint about how I might integrate this with an alertdialog for the checkbox list?

Comment: Write your own custom adapter which shows the list of titles with checkboxes. Set your custom adapter to dialog. AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  builder.setAdapter(adapter, listener). listener is to listen for every item in the list.